# TypeScript - SetTimeOut bug on variable assign

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, boolean, settimeout

I am working with Ionic and Angular wich means that I am working with TypeScript language.

I have a boolean that is supposed to become `false` if there is a click on an element and if that same boolean is `true`. After the boolean becomes false a `setTimeOut()` function is runned so that after 5000ms the boolean becomes `true` again.

The problem I am facing is when the `setTimeOut()` is runned. The boolean becomes `true`. However when I click on the element again (after 5000ms) the boolean is `false` ...

Where is the code:

```
resendSMS() {
  console.log('allowResendSMS: ', this.allowResendSMS);

  if (this.allowResendSMS) {
    this.allowResendSMS = false;
    console.log('SMS HAS BEEN RESENDED');
    console.log('allowResendSMS: ', this.allowResendSMS);

    setTimeout(function () {

      this.allowResendSMS = true;
      console.log('END OF TIMEOUT');
      console.log('allowResendSMS: ', this.allowResendSMS)

    }, 5000);
  } 
}
```

Where is the output:

```
(First Click on Element)
allowResendSMS:  true
SMS HAS BEEN RESENDED
allowResendSMS:  false
END OF TIMEOUT
allowResendSMS:  true

(Second Click on Element)
allowResendSMS:  false
END OF TIMEOUT
allowResendSMS:  true
```

Can someone give a clue of why the allowresendSMS is `false` on the second click and even why it's beeing runned the `setTimeOut()` when this boolean haves a `false` value ... ?

Comment: Use arrow function to refer `this` to the scope of the class: `setTimeout(() => {...}, 5000);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your code the `this` in `this.allowResendSMS = true` scopes to the function (the context of `this` changes), not the surrounding class.

Replace

```
setTimeout(function () {
  this.allowResendSMS = true;
  console.log('END OF TIMEOUT');
  console.log('allowResendSMS: ', this.allowResendSMS)
}, 5000);
```

with

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.allowResendSMS = true;
  console.log('END OF TIMEOUT');
  console.log('allowResendSMS: ', this.allowResendSMS)
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer! Your solution is working!